# Customizing the UIScrollbar in Flash CS4

Tags: flash, scrollbar, components, customization, cs4

Are you able to customize the UIScrollbar component in Flash CS4?

Answer (score 0):

check these tutorial
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/xml/build-a-dynamic-guest-book-with-xml-and-actionscript-30/